# Ruby on Rails - Source a file and save ENV variable as global

Tags: ruby-on-rails, constants, global, env

I have an API key which I've saved to `/home/user/api/keys` that I would like to save as a global variable in my Rails app. I thought this would work, this is my `config/initializers/my_constants.rb`:

```
`source "/home/user/api/keys"`
API_PASS = ENV["API_PASSWORD"]
```

And this is `/home/user/api/keys` (without the real value, obviously):

```
#!/bin/bash
export API_PASSWORD="--------"
```

The source command doesn't seem to do anything. API_PASS is just set to nil. How can I do this?

Comment: Why not just set the environment variable in your shell?

Comment: @DaveNewton - I'd like to automate it. So I think I will make a script that calls the source command and then deploys the server. But I think I will still have to open the file and parse it out when I deal with my cron tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above won't work because the backtick command starts its own shell and ends it so those variables are never included in the rest of your script.

I think you'll have to parse the file yourself and add the entries to ENV.  I would look at the dotenv gem and see if you can point it at your own environment file.  They've done all the hard work for you.

https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv

Comment: I think I'm going to create a script that uses the source command and then deploys for this then. I think I'll have to parse out the file when I'm dealing with this password in a cron task tho. I might just open the file and parse contents with regex myself. Thank you for explaining why the back ticks were failing!